# Using CiviRules to send SMS via Twilio

Tags: civirules, sms, twilio

I have the Twilio extension installed and working for sending individual SMS messages. However, I don't see any way to trigger an SMS message via CiviRules. Has this not been developed or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to install SMS API extension https://civicrm.org/extensions/sms-api

Comment: Thank you! Is there an other functionality developed for this like being able to text a group?